# How to preselected the default shipping address in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.8

Please help..I'm new in magento 2 code. 
If the shipping address is the default shipping address, how to preselected it without ticking the radio button or any button under Magento 2

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding an observer for the event `sales_quote_address_collect_totals_before`

https://mage2gen.com/load/8cfec17a-a5ff-481e-9f36-2091e0237006

Then apply the Customers Default Shipping address as shown below:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Sales;

class QuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer
     */
    private $customer;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $customerAddressRepository;

    /**
     * QuoteAddressCollectTotalsBefore constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $customerAddressRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session  $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $customerAddressRepository
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->customerAddressRepository = $customerAddressRepository;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        if (!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            return;
        }
        $customer = $this->getCustomer();
        $quote->setCustomerId($customer);
        $quoteAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if ($quoteAddress->getFirstname()) {
            return;
        }
        if ($defaultShipping = $this->getCustomer()->getDefaultShipping()) {
            $quoteAddress->importCustomerAddressData(
                $this->customerAddressRepository->getById(
                    $defaultShipping
                )
            );
        }
    }

    public function getCustomer()
    {
        if (!$this->customer) {
            $this->customer = $this->customerSession->getCustomer();
        }
        return $this->customer;
    }
}
```